# How might I retrieve the values associated with indices of a Pandas Index object?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Suppose I were to

```py
common_indices = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
```

which yields a `<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>` object, how might I retreive the values associated with another dataframe (e.g. `df3`).

As attempting

```py
sub_df3 = df3.where(df3.index == common_indices)
```

yields a `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `df3`? When you do `df3.index == common_indices` what it's trying to do is create an array of true-falses from an element-wise equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc`:

```
df3.loc[common_indices]
```

##### Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index = range(9), data=np.random.randint(low=100,size=(9,3)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = [1,2,3,4,5], data=np.random.randint(low=100,size=(5,3)))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index = range(9), data=np.random.randint(low=100,size=(9,3)))

>>> df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
Int64Index([1, 3, 5], dtype='int64')

>>> df3.loc[df1.index.intersection(df2.index)]
    0   1   2
1  90  33  99
3  90  41  43
5   3  10  12
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df3.loc[common_indices]
```

Not to be confused with:

```
df3.loc(common_indices)
```

Which yields a `TypeError`